# Where is the access token in the URL that Facebook returns?

Tags: python, facebook, oauth-2.0

I made a request to authenticate server side into Facebook for my Django application.

```
def authenticateViaFacebook(request):                   
  '''
  Redirects users to a page that allows for Facebook login.
  '''
  consumer = oauth2.Consumer(
      key = settings.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      secret = settings.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)

  # Request token URL for Facebook.
  request_token_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"

  # Create client.
  client = oauth2.Client(consumer)

  # Other arguments to Facebook.
  otherArguments = 'client_id=' + settings.FACEBOOK_APP_ID
  otherArguments += '&scope=email'
  otherArguments += '&redirect_uri=' + settings.SITE_URL
  otherArguments += 'authenticationRedirect/facebook'
  otherArguments += '&secret=' + settings.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET


  # The OAuth Client request works just like httplib2 for the most part.
  res, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET", otherArguments)

  # Examine the response.
  return HttpResponse(str(res))
```

I got this response from Facebook.

```
{'status': '200', 'content-length': '15753', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 
 'content-location': u'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?oauth_body_hash=1YZMc0vtMcUa5nO81ZkuwoCSct4%3D&oauth_nonce=14826580&oauth_timestamp=1342669603&oauth_consumer_key=117889941688718&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=t2cIAmQYs4r5IqcsoODqorFIHbs%3D',  
 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
 'expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'connection': 'keep-alive',
 '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 
 'cache-control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 
 'date': 'Thu, 19 Jul 2012 03:46:44 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'DENY', 
 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 
 'x-fb-debug': 'cXSDiq5jL9ZffjalabM6QKEgr50QOhPJsNlHW2MpSSQ='}
```

I am a bit confused because I do not see a variable called "access token" I even see weird terms like `auth_signature_method` and `oauth_signature`, but I have no idea what they mean.

How do I retrieve the access token from Facebook? Furthermore, how can I use this access token to retrieve basic information such as "name" from the user? The access token is just a string, right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know with your code. But if you use Facebook graph api it would be simple.

```
def authorize(self):

        warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
        savout = os.dup(1)
        os.close(1)
        os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)
        try:
            webbrowser.open(FBOAuth.FACEBOOK_GRAPH_URL+'/oauth/authorize?'+urllib.urlencode(
                                {'client_id':FBOAuth.CLIENT_ID,
                                 'redirect_uri':FBOAuth.REDIRECT_URI,
                                 'scope':'read_stream, publish_stream'}))
        finally:
            os.dup2(savout, 1)

        FBOAuth.SECRET_CODE = raw_input("Secret Code: ")
        self.save_secret_code(FBOAuth.SECRET_CODE)

        return FBOAuth.SECRET_CODE

def access_token(self):
if not FBOAuth.SECRET_CODE:
    FBOAuth.SECRET_CODE = self.authorize()

args = {'redirect_uri': FBOAuth.REDIRECT_URI,
        'client_id' : FBOAuth.CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret':FBOAuth.CLIENT_SECRET,
        'code':FBOAuth.SECRET_CODE,}

access_token = urllib.urlopen(FBOAuth.FACEBOOK_GRAPH_URL + "/oauth/access_token?" + urllib.urlencode(args)).read()
access_token = urlparse.parse_qs(access_token)
FBOAuth.ACCESS_TOKEN = access_token['access_token'][0]
self.save_access_token(FBOAuth.ACCESS_TOKEN)
return FBOAuth.ACCESS_TOKEN
```

And by these 2 functions you can get access tokens.
[Here](http://task3.cc/376/handle-facebook-oauth-authentication-with-python-sdk/) is the link for tutorial i used.
[Facebook graph api documents](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just like most auth processes, you pass in your app ID, and get back a "code." In a second "GET", you send that in for the access_token. You need to decrypt the result, which may be in HMAC. Use the SDK to manage these functions, as the other person recommended, and it will be easier.

"auth_signature_method" means the way in which the encrypted signature was signed. It's not the final access_token you can use to query the user's data on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong in several ways, mainly in forgetting that you need to have a user participate in the transaction.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ for the the steps to follow, these are actually pretty simple and you can do them all by hand using curl.